# What is the best approach to threading 2 web service calls and combining resulting data in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

What would be the best approach to threading 2 processes and combining resulting data from the resulting calls? I am currently interfacing with 2 web services. I would like to call one web service A for say DataA in one thread. Then call web service B for DataB in another thread. I would then need to retrieve particular info from DataA and DataB to create DataC. I would also need to be able to cancel the entire process at any point.

I've been looking into using ThreadPool but there isn't a way to cancel any ThreadPool threads.

UPDATE: Currently using C# .NET 4.0

Answer (score 5):

I would use the Task Parallel Library (TPL, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

```
List<Data> GetData(CancellationToken cancel)
{
 List<Data> dataA;
 List<Data> dataB;
 Task[] tasks = new Task[]
 {
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DataA()),
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DataNB()),
 };

 Task.WaitAll(tasks, cancel); // Block until all tasks complete or cancelled.
 if (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
   return new List<Data>();
 return dataA.Concat(dataB);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the CancellationToken for a web service call?

Comment: The Task.WaitAll() takes a CancellationToken as well. What happens if a CancellationToken is passed to the Task.WaitAll() and the WaitAll is cancelled? What happens to the threads that were launched?

Comment: Your threads will continue to run until they receive the web service response or a timeout.  If the WaitAll is cancelled, the tasks will just end.  So, after the Task.WaitAll add `if (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested) return null;`

Comment: I'm confused a little. You said that if the WaitAll is passed a CancellationToken and it is cancelled, the tasks will just end. Therefore it no longer blocks at the WaitAll call. But then you said the threads will continue to run regardless that the WaitAll was stopped?

Comment: On cancellation the WaitAll will unblock, so you main thread will continue.  The threads running the tasks, will still continue.  When they finally receive a response or timeout, they should test the cancellation token and just return if set.

Answer (score 1):

Give the WaitHandle class a look in the System.Threading namespace.  WaitAll will give the the ability to block until a number of threads have completed.

Comment: Can the WaitHandle class be used with any of the .Net threading options such as BackgroundWorkers? I've already taken a look at the sample using the WaitHandle class in conjunction with the ThreadPool and it serves my purpose well except for that you can't abort ThreadPool threads.